# Converting polygons to lines and finding intersection between lines and polygons from another layer using QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, polygon

I am using QGIS 3.16.2 (Hannover) in windows 10.

I have three two different layers of polygons.

[image]

How do I find the intersection point between the polygons (Pink ones) and the buildings (Violet ones)?

I was thinking first I can make the centerline of the seperated polygons (pink ones). Then I can extend the line to the polygon and find the intersection.

I have tried to use the r.thin from grass, but I in QGIS I cannot create any output. I tried to define the center points of each seperated polygons (Pink ones) and connect them using the point to path. However, there is no order in the points which are created, so it was also not possible.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Polygons to Lines](https://docs.qgis.org/2.6/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vector_geometry_tools/polygonstolines.html) tool to convert the polygons to lines.  Then use the [Line Intersections](https://docs.qgis.org/2.6/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vector_overlay_tools/lineintersections.html) tool to create points where the resulting two line datasets intersect.
Both tools are standard tools in the Processing toolbox.